# Not able to set cookie on apache server using php and laravel

Tags: php, apache, cookies, session-cookies, laravel-5.5

I have laravel 5.5 set up on my local machine everything is working fine the default laravel XSRF token and cookies are getting set but when i deployed my project to server then the default XSRF token and cookies are not being set.

Comment: Is there a difference in your PHP config on the deployed machine?

Comment: yes proxy and reverse proxy module is installed on my deployed machine because on my deployed machine some other projects are also running.

Comment: Can you check your HTTP logs on the server and locally to see any differences at the time of trying to set the token and cookies?

Also are database entries being added for the XSRF tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved my issues after struggling 2 days , i did the `phpinfo()` on my local machine as well as server and find one difference in **session block** , on my local machine it was file and on my server it was file memcache file so this is due to **memcache** install on the server , so if we will use any inplace memory strategy like memcache , redis then the default path for session might have changed.